# How to globally override Mongoid::Document._id generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I wanna override the kind of _id generation in mongoid (another app, which shares the db uses `String` instead of `ObjectId()`

I can do it for every model by adding this:

```
    field :_id, type: String, default: -> { BSON::ObjectId.new.to_s }
```

But how to globally attach this to keep it DRY?

Comment: You forgot to add which mongoid version you are using.

TBH, I don't see a point in doing this. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Version 5.1.x. I wanna connect my `RoR` app to a `meteor` hosted `mongoDb`. And this `meteor app` writes the mongoDb ObjectId as a String. If I do not overwrite the `mongoid` _id, it will not fetch entries created by the meteor app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very valid usecase but [looking into the code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/fields.rb#L53-L57) you might be out of luck at Mongoid::Fields, but you could overwrite `mongoize` which should go like this

```
Item.new.id
 => BSON::ObjectId('56e727892ada693ea8000000')

class BSON::ObjectId
  def self.mongoize(k)
    k.to_s
  end
end

Item.new.id
 => "56e7276f2ada693737000002"
```

Comment: Hm, seems to be working, but `Item.find(params[:id])` does not work anymore.  `message:
  Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 56e728dfa54d752083e7435a.
summary:
  When calling User.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 56e728dfa54d752083e7435a ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 56e728dfa54d752083e7435a.`

Comment: how old is your metor app? I'm asking because for quite some time there's an option in Metor to store the id proper and not just as a string: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_collection

Comment: It's new. After you suggested to update, I created a new one (1.2.1): Here is a gist https://gist.github.com/mediatainment/b451b021fbb34e61f3f6

Comment: I found out, it's not allowed to override the `users`-collection at meteor.  `meteor-accounts` They supply id generation with `string`s and does not allow `ObjectId`s. But all other Meteor collections can simply drop `Users = new Mongo.Collection('users', {idGeneration: 'MONGO'});`. This is annoying!